# Is there a way to send props and function in one onClick event?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

After few hours of searching for the right answer I couldn't find it nowhere. I will try to explain my situation as best as I can. I have an Image Carousel on my website that I want to be opened when the user triggers and clicks the image. So basically I have 5 images on my website and whichever image user select it should open it in the image carousel. Everything works perfectly and I made it to this part. So I have a page file in which is all the code for the page where the carousel is. Then I have the file just for the image section component in which I send the `handleViewPhotosClick` function (this function opens image carousel) as props from the main page. So in this file I detect which image has been clicked and send its number to Image Carousel component with updated state (its a number which is used to open the right image).

But the issue is that I can't pass `handleViewPhotosClick` and `handleSelectedImage` in one onClick, or I just don't know the right syntax.

I won't write the full code, I will just replicate it.

**ListingPage** (Main page):

```
export default class ListingPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      imageCarouselOpen: false
    };
  }
  render() {
    const handleViewPhotosClick = (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      this.setState({
        imageCarouselOpen: true // This opens carousel
      });
    };
    return (
      <SectionImages
        handleViewPhotosClick={handleViewPhotosClick} {/* Passing handleViewPhotosClick to SectionImages */}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

**SectionImages** (Images section):

```
export default class SectionImages extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = { 
      selectedImage: null,
      number: 0
    }
  }
  handleSelectedImage(number) {
    this.setState({ selectedImage: number });
  }
  render() {
    const { handleViewPhotosClick } = this.props;

    const imageItem = (itemClass, imagePath, number) => {
      return (
        // Is there a way to append handleViewPhotosClick to the bellow onClick function?
        <div className={itemClass} onClick={() => { this.handleSelectedImage(number) }}> 
            <img src={imagePath} alt={number} />
        </div>
      );
    };

    return (
      <div>
      {imageItem(itemClass, imagePath, 0 )} {/* 0 stands for unique image number I pass */}
      {imageItem(itemClass, imagePath, 1)} {/* 1 stands for unique image number I pass */}
      <Modal>
        <ImageCarousel selectedImage={this.state.selectedImage} /> {/* passing the props to the image carousel component which I then use in ImageCarousel constructor */}
      </Modal>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

So basically I'm trying to add `handleViewPhotosClick` to the `imageItem` onClick function. I know that we can pass multiple functions in one onClick call but how can I pass props + function. Hope I was clear enough. I'm new to React so this might be wrong approach from me, and any help will mean a lot. Thanks!

Comment: what props do you wanna pass?

Comment: cant you just  do :  onClick={() => { this.handleSelectedImage(number) ; handleViewPhotosClick();}}
?

Comment: Just add `this.props.handleViewPhotosClick()` inside `handleSelectedImage`

Comment: @wentjun Hello! Ok, so I to put handleViewPhotosClick (in ListingPage its a function which then I pass as props to SectionImages) and then I want to include handleViewPhotosClick and new handleSelectedImage in one onClick event in the imageItem function inside SectionImages.

Comment: @GalAbra Thanks for the solution! When I add it and click on the image I get this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined"

Comment: @TomSlutsky Hello Tom and thanks for your solution. I have added it exaclty as you wrote and after clicking image I also get this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined` is because you passed `number` as a parameter.

To test this behaviour, this is what you can do:

```
const handleViewPhotosClick = (value) => {
  console.log(value);

  // handle the rest
};
```

If you wish to pass the event object as well, this is what you should do on the `SectionImages` component:

```
<div className={itemClass} onClick={(e) => { this.handleSelectedImage(e, number) }}> 
  <img src={imagePath} alt={number} />
</div>
```

And on the `ListingsPage` component,

```
const handleViewPhotosClick = (e, value: number) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(value);

  // handle the rest
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a function that was passed as a prop, you can always do that from inside another function. Just make sure to pass it the correct arguments (in this case, the event):

```js
export default class SectionImages extends Component {
  /* constructor */

  handleSelectedImage(e, number) {
    this.props.handleViewPhotosClick(e);
    this.setState({ selectedImage: number });
  }

  render() {
    const imageItem = (itemClass, imagePath, number) => {
      return (
        <div className={itemClass} onClick={e => this.handleSelectedImage(e, number)}> 
            <img src={imagePath} alt={number} />
        </div>
      );
    };

    /* return statement */
  }
}
```